# Persisting an output in comb logic block

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga

I'm having an issue persisting the value of gpo.
I want it to change only at the point in the code below.

```
gpo_int <= gpo_int when n_wr = '1';
gpo <= gpo_int;
write : process(n_en, n_wr) begin
  if n_wr = '0' and n_en='0' then
    case addr(15 downto 12) is
      when x"f" => -- i/o
        case addr(11 downto 8) is
          when x"0" => -- gpo
            gpo_int <= data;
          when others =>
            gpo_int <= gpo_int;
        end case;
      when others =>
        gpo_int <=  gpo_int;
    end case;
  end if;
end process;
```

gpo_int is a signal of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"00";

Firstly gpo_int is not persisted properly (I can see gpo change to x"00" when n_rw goes to '1'. Also is there any way of doing this more neatly (defining the truth table for the comb logic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking for a latch.  In FPGAs particularly, that's not usually the right thing to do (for a variety of reasons).

Can you not use a clocked process to create the persistence you need using a flipflop?

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if n_wr = '0' and n_en ='0' and addr(11 downto 8) = x"F0" then
           gpo_int <= data;
        end if;
     end if;
end process;
gpo <= gpo_int;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each concurrent statement that assigns a signal has a driver for that signal.  A concurrent signal assignment (in this case a conditional signal assignment) is a concurrent statement.  A process is a concurrent statement.

So there are two drivers:

```
gpo <= gpo_int;
```

and:

```
write : process
```

std_logic_vector is a resolved data type.  The effective value of od the std_logic_vector signal `gpo_int`  is the resolved value of all it's drivers (and you have two showing).  For each element of `gpo_int` the corresponding value from each of the two drivers is used to determine the effective value of `gpo_int` by looking up the value at the intersection of the two values using the resolution table defined in the body of package std_logic_1164:

```
CONSTANT resolution_table : stdlogic_table := (
--      ---------------------------------------------------------
--      |  U    X    0    1    Z    W    L    H    -        |   |
--      ---------------------------------------------------------
        ( 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U' ), -- | U |
        ( 'U', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' ), -- | X |
        ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X' ), -- | 0 |
        ( 'U', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'X' ), -- | 1 |
        ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', 'X' ), -- | Z |
        ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'X' ), -- | W |
        ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'X' ), -- | L |
        ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'H', 'W', 'W', 'H', 'X' ), -- | H |
        ( 'U', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X' )  -- | - |
    );
```

So right off the bat you can have a conflict caused by the stored value (`gpo_int <= gpo_int when n_wr = '1'`) and the assigned value from the process when their corresponding elements don't *resolve* to the same value.

For instance if `gpo_int(7)` of one driver is a `'1'` and the other driver is a `'0'` the resolved value of that element is `'X'`.

If you want to operate `gpo_int` as a latch try:

```
gpo <= gpo_int;

WRITE:
    process (n_en, n_wr, data)
        begin
        if n_wr = '0' and n_en ='0' and addr(11 downto 8) = x"F0" then
            gpo_int <= data;
        else
            gpo_int <= gpo_int;  -- the else clause is optional for some synthesis tools
        end if;

    end process;
```

And forget the concurrent signal assignment statement to `gpo_int`. The process statement assigned `gpo_int` retains it's value accept when all three conditions in the if statement are true.

The reason `data` is listed in the sensitivity list, is in case it transitions after `n_wr` or `n_en`.

You can find a description of the recognized way to infer a latch in the now rescinded IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 6.2.1.1 Level sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list, or your vendor's documentation describing supported VHDL language constructs.

Typically a system will insure you don't get combinatorial 'glitches' on the latch enable for a register by insuring one of the steering signals (`n_wr` and `n_en` in this case) transitions inside the other signals transitions (e.g. `addr` is stable).  And yes you can get combinatorial events one delta cycle long in a zero time model.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. I landed up taking the easy way out and changed the entire design to sequential. It was just simpler as I had numerous other signals with the same issue (not just gpo). It solved all the problems however I still want to learn - and your answer has sorted it out in my head. I may even try implementing it as you suggest at some point to make sure that I get it!